# HTML 5 base template for drupal 6

Tags: html, templates, drupal, drupal-6

I tend to use zen but am really looking for an html5 base template for a D6 site I have inherited. Zen only seems to be html5 for D7.

Any good templates? I tried omega once but did not really like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think omega is the best choice, but you can try this options:

- https://drupal.org/project/boron
- https://drupal.org/project/basic
- https://drupal.org/project/framework

Regards.

Comment: great, thanks. I think boron will work for me, the layout is really simple.